# Padding error in as3Crypto when trying to work a-sync

Tags: flex3, as3crypto

I'm trying to encrypt/decrypt files in flex (AIR) using the *as3crypto* package.
the problem is that when attempting to process slightly large files (over 5M) the process time gets ridiculously long and the client freezes (get the "not responding" title)
so i tried to go Async and encrypt/decrypt a chunk at a time and interlace it with the frame refresh rate.

the encryption goes smooth, or so it seems, but when i try to decrypt the result back to the original document i get a padding error:
"**Error: PKCS#5:unpad: Invalid padding value. expected [252], found [152]**"

my code is like so (between initiation and finalization):

- the **run** method gets called repeatedly until the file is completed
- _**buffer** contains the byte array from the source file
- _**result** the result
- **CHUNK** is the bite size of bytes that i process each time
- the cipher is initiated as: Crypto.getCipher("aes-ecb", _key, Crypto.getPad("pkcs5"));

  ```
  public function run(data:Object):Boolean{

      if((_buffer.length-_position)>CHUNK){
          processChunk(_position,CHUNK);
          _position += CHUNK;
          var e:ProgressEvent = new ProgressEvent(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,false,false,_position,_buffer.length);
          this.dispatchEvent(e);
          return true;
      }else if(!_isFinnalized){
          processChunk(_position,_buffer.length - _position);
          this.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
          finnalize();

      }

      return false;
  }


  private function processChunk(position:uint,chunk:uint):void{
      var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
      buffer.writeBytes(_buffer,position,chunk);
       if(_action==ENCRYPT){
          _aes.encrypt(buffer);
      }else{
          _aes.decrypt(buffer);
      } 
      _result.writeBytes(buffer);


  }
  ```

help me, please!

Answer (score 0):

..found the bug.

the encryption and decryption actions change the actual chunk size.
in the **processChunck** method, the ByteArray length before encryption was 16400 and after changed to 16416.
using the decrypt changes the ByteArray length from 16416 back to 16400.

hence the solution i chose was to use two numeric values, one for each method used.

I have no idea why this happens, its not the padding (tested it with *Crypto.getPad("none")*).

I'll be posting the code on my blog in a day or two.
(http://giladmanor.com)

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth checking out this http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/06/04/as3crypto-rsa-padding-function-returned-null-bug-of-death-fix/